# Prove that $|\mathbb R^n | = |\mathbb R|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that $|\mathbb{R}^n| = |\mathbb{R}|$.

It will be enough to prove $|\mathbb{R}^{2}|=|\mathbb{R}|$. We can further simplify by proving      $|(0,1)\times(0,1)| = |(0,1)|$ (because $|\mathbb{R}|=|(0,1)|$).

BUT how to proceed further?

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb R$ to be where you put IR?

Comment: Schröder-Bernstein-Cantor will help you here, but then you need to find an injection from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes it means R set of real numbers